# Impementing a hashtable as a attribute , using methos add or remove elements

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, hashmap

I'm trying to make a code that includes a superclass person and a subclass teacher that has as an attribute a map that contains the subjects that the teacher has, a code for every subject, and the number of subjects. I made a hashmap and created 2 other classes, subjects and codes. But I can't find a method to add or remove elements from the hashmap because every subject must correspond to a code.

In the classes subjects and codes I made two array lists as attributes.

```
public class Teacher extends Person {

    private int nr;
    private  Map<ArrayList<subjects>, ArrayList<codes>> c;

    public Teacher(String name, String email,int nr, Map<ArrayList<subjects>,ArrayList<codes>>c ){
        super(name, email);
        this.c=c;
    }

    public int getNr() {
        return nr;
    }

    public void setNr(int nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }

    public Map<ArrayList<subjects>, ArrayList<codes>> getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Map<ArrayList<subjects>, ArrayList<codes>> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}

class subjects {
    private ArrayList<String> subjects;


    public subjects(ArrayList<String> subjects) {

        this.subjects = subjects;
    } 

    public ArrayList<String> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(ArrayList<String> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}

class codes {

    private ArrayList<Integer> codes;

    public Codes(ArrayList<Integer> codes) {
        this.codes = codes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you don't understand how map works. Your code can look like following.

```
private  Map<String, String> subjectsByCodes = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void addSubject(String code, String subject){
    subjectsByCodes.put(code, subject);
}

public String getSubject(String code){
    return subjectsByCodes.get(code);
}

public int getNumberOfSubject(){
    return subjectsByCodes.getSize();
}
```

Adding subjects to a teacher:

```
teacher.addSubect("code-A", "subject-A");
teacher.addSubect("code-B", "subject-B");
teacher.addSubect("code-C", "subject-C");
```

Retrieving a subject by a code:

```
teacher.getSubject("code-C");
```

You don't need the number of subjects as a separate attribute. You can get it at any time via map:

```
teacher.getNumberOfSubjects()
```